# Script Contents of SQL Server Database From a Batch File

Tags: sql-server, command-line, scripting, smo

I want to be able to script the schema of a given database into a .sql file from the Windows command prompt. Basically, I want to execute the "Generate Scripts" feature of Management Studio programmatically.

I know this is possible using .NET and SMO, but is there something built-in to do this?

Background to this question: This is meant as a simple auditing instrument. We want to capture the schema every night. Any primitive, low-tech solution works for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built-in from the command line.

If you have Red Gate SQL Compare you can do it:

```
sqlcompare /s1:MySQLInstance /db1:MyDB /mkscr:MyDB_Schema /q
```

SSMS scripting functions are just wrappers for SMO.  I know you mention it, but you could write a powershell script to use SMO.

This is adapted from code found on this [**Simple Talk post**](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/).

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")

$serverName = "MYSQLINSTANCE"
$databaseName = "MyDB"
$sqlServer = new-object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $serverName
$sqlDb = $sqlServer.Databases[$databasename]

$options = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions")
$options.ExtendedProperties = $true
$options.DRIAll = $true
$options.Indexes = $true
$options.Triggers = $true
$options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true
$options.Filename = "c:\\script_folder\\mydb_schema.sql"
$options.IncludeHeaders = $true
$options.ToFileOnly = $true

$transfer = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer") $sqlDb
$transfer.options = $options
$transfer.ScriptTransfer()
```

Comment: Actually if you are using SQLPS, or the SQL server snapin it does have the Script() method. Which I guess is border line "built in". Check: http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2010/05/script-sql-objects-with-powershell/ it has a ton of the videos Sean and Jen McCown did on using PowerShell for this type of thing.

Comment: I think this is pretty workable. I'll probably do a powershell script then.

Comment: @Shawn that's a good point.  I'm still pretty green with the PS snap-ins.  I'll have to play with that.  I'm pretty used to SMO from the C# side of things so my brain navigates that direction still.

Comment: SQLPS is convenient for when you don't have access to your script library. I will admit I only have a handful of functions/scripts that actually depend on it. SQLPS is convient when you just don't really want to open SSMS :) However, most scripts I try to write for multiple versions of SQL Server so SMO has the advantage in that instance.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote an open source command line utility named [SchemaZen](https://github.com/sethreno/schemazen#schemazen---script-and-create-sql-server-objects-quickly) that does this. It's much faster than scripting from management studio and it's output is more version control friendly. It supports scripting both schema and data.

To generate scripts run:

```
schemazen.exe script --server localhost --database db --scriptDir c:\somedir
```

Then to recreate the database from scripts run:

```
schemazen.exe create --server localhost --database db --scriptDir c:\somedir
```

Answer (score 4):

To just feed off of [squillman's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25104/507) answer this is to show a sample of what SQLPS can do for you...You can browse each "directory" under the database and just do a `get-member -MemberType Method`, looking for `Script()`. Most of the directories have it I believe.

```
Add-PSSnapin *SQL*
# Note my hostname of the server is "SQLSERVER"
# To show object names to be scripted
dir SQLSERVER:\SQL\SQLSERVER\DEFAULT\Databases\JProCo\Tables | Select Name
$objects = dir SQLSERVER:\SQL\SQLSERVER\DEFAULT\Databases\JProCo\Tables
$objects | % {$_.Script()}
```

Look from real server:
[image: Screenshot from my test server]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard.

If you don't have it installed then you can grab version 1.2 from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=119368)

The installer doesn't give any indication that it has installed but if you open up a command window and navigate to:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Publishing\1.2` the `SqlPubWiz.exe` should be there.

You can use this to script out your schema.

Type `SqlPubWiz help script` in your command window and it will give you the options you need.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this. It does seem from the help command that a lot of scripting options are not available though. I hope this captures all the important stuff.